# Javascript/jquery - Add a class to list at variable position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable which contains an item number ... like this:

```
myvariable = '3'; //Note: This is currently a string so it might need converting?
```

Then I have the code which populates the listview:

```
$('#listview').live("pageinit", function(){
$.getJSON("myjson.json", function(data){
    $.each(data.unis, function(index, value){


        $('<li><a class="listitem" href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>').insertAfter('#' + value.sortLetter);

        $('#' + value.sortLetter).show();

    });

    $("#listview").listview("refresh");


});
```

All the above works fine.

Now, what I need to do it to insert a class into the item which is at the position myvariable value.

So, if myvariable is `3` then the listview will look like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="listitem" href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>
<li><a class="listitem" href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>
<li><a class="listitem AddedClassHere" href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>
</ul>
```

if myvariable was to be `1` then:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="listitem AddedClassHere" href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>
<li><a class="listitem" href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>
<li><a class="listitem" href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>
</ul>
```

and so on...

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:eq()` selector, note that `:eq()` is zero-based.

```
$('ul li:eq("'+ (myvariable-1) +'") a').addClass('class');
```

Or:

```
$('ul li').eq(myvariable-1).find('a').addClass('class');
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to build the class list dynamically for each item, optionally adding your class if the index matches the magic number that you specify in your variable. Change your code to this:

```
$.each(data.unis, function(index, value){
    var classList = 'listItem';
    if(index == (myvariable - 1)) {
        classList += ' addedClass';
    }
    $('<li><a class="' + classList + '" href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>').insertAfter('#' + value.sortLetter);

    $('#' + value.sortLetter).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also an eq() method:

```
$('ul li').eq(myvariable - 1).find("a").addClass('class');
```

se http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ for more docs.

Note: Watch out if you are using multiple (or nested) ul on same page, then you need a different approach...

Comment: It adds the class to `li` element instead of anchor link.